# Flutter MissingPluginException when using custom plugin for chat heads

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter app where I'm trying to implement a custom plugin for chat heads (similar to Facebook Messenger chat heads). I've followed the recommended steps for creating a Flutter plugin that communicates with native Android code (Kotlin and Java), but I'm consistently getting the following error:
Failed to show chat head: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method showChatHead on channel quick_nav).
Here's an overview of my setup:

I have a Flutter package named quick_nav that contains Dart code (quick_nav.dart) for method channel communication.
In my native Android code (Kotlin and Java), I have a service named ChatHeadService.kt that handles the chat head functionality.
The Dart code and Kotlin/Java code use the same channel name ("quick_nav") and method name ("showChatHead").
Despite following the Flutter and native Android guidelines for plugin development, I'm still encountering this issue. Here are some additional details:

I've ensured that my plugin is properly registered in my Dart code.
I've tried stopping and restarting my Flutter app to make sure that changes in the native code take effect.
The error message suggests that Flutter can't find the native implementation for the showChatHead method.

**Main.dart**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBdnl.png)

**quick_nav.dart**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKAin.png)

**chatheadservice.kt**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJaX7.png)

**MainActivity.kt**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpzNq.png)

**QuickNavPlugin.kt**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WwRn.png)

Checked that the method name and channel name in my Dart code (quick_nav.dart) match those in my Kotlin code (QuickNavPlugin.kt).
Ensured that my plugin is properly registered in my Dart code's main function.
Stopped and restarted my Flutter app to apply changes in the native code.
Reviewed the Flutter documentation and native Android guidelines for plugin development.
Despite these efforts, I continue to receive the 'MissingPluginException' error, indicating that the implementation for the showChatHead method on channel quick_nav is not found. I was expecting that my custom plugin for chat heads would work seamlessly.